# «Святитель» — с прописной или строчной буквы?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, названия

Есть Клинический медицинский многопрофильный центр Святителя Луки.
Стоит ли писать «святитель» с большой буквы? Название не церковное ведь? И еще насчет «клинический» с большой буквы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот разъяснения "Грамоты" ([Названия ликов святых](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/pravosl0/pravosl5/)).

> Пишутся со строчной буквы:
> апостолы, мученики, святители, преподобные и т. д. Именование того или иного святого с именем собственным или без имени – со строчной буквы: святитель Спиридон, преподобный Серафим, «апостол посетил Коринф» и т. д.
> Исключения: Преподобный Сергий, Святитель и Чудотворец Николай.

Вполне возможно, что такое неверное написание (Святителя Луки) здесь ошибочно перекликается с написанием слова ["святой"](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9) (но медицинский центр — это не собор, не храм, не топоним):

> *в сочетании с последующим собственным именем пишется со строчной буквы, напр.*: святой Владимир, святой Николай, святая Екатерина, святая Ольга; но (*с предшествующим собственным именем, в названиях соборов, храмов, орденов, в геогр. наименованиях*) **Святой**, *напр.*: Владимир Святой, собор Святого Петра, орден Святого Александра Невского, орден Святого апостола Андрея Первозванного, остров Святой Елены, залив (остров, река) Святого Лаврентия, горы Святого Ильи, площадь Святого Марка, храм Всех Святых, *также*: Неделя Всех Святых.

Comment: да, я тоже думаю, что раз не собор и не храм, то не с большой... Спасибо!

Comment: @flossyU: а меня чего не заметили?

Comment: @flossyU: простите, не надо лишать Римму принятого ответа, я этого не имел в виду! Просто ждал, что как-то прокомментируете и мой ответ. ;)

Answer (score 1):

«Клинический» с большой должен быть, насколько я понимаю, поскольку в названиях обычно первое слово пишется с большой буквы. А «святитель» с маленькой. Такие слова и в церковных текстах не пишут с прописной, только само имя. И «святой» тоже с маленькой буквы.

Comment: Ваш ответ помог разобраться, как никакой другой... Спасибо ;-)

Comment: Очень рад, спасибо!)